# Console warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

Tags: ios

"Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!"

I'm trying to have my app go to a loading screen upon selecting a picture to upload. This works by, upon selecting a picture, removing the UIImagePickerController scene, adding the Loading scene, and once the upload is complete, removing the Loading scene.

```
-(void)uploadMessage{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];


LoadingViewController *loadView = [[LoadingViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoadView" bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:loadView animated:NO completion:^{

    NSData *fileData;
    NSString *fileName;
    NSLog(@"Image");
    fileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image);
    fileName = @"image.png";


PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:fileData];
[self.game setObject:file forKey:@"picture"];
[self.game saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if(succeeded){
     [self removeAndChangeButtons];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    }

    }];
}];

}
```

Comment: Do you really need to show loading in a new view controller? How about just showing a progress HUD and let the upload happen on another thread. Everything can be done in the same controller. Even if it needs to be a full page HUD, you can create a sub view and show whatever loading status you want. Also would recommend using storyboard instead of nibs

Comment: Ok i'll look into that. I used initially had it in my storyboard however it had very weird / wrong behaviour. The screen would lag and then load black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

```
- (void) showMessage:(NSString*)message withTitle:(NSString*)title onView:(UIView*)view removeAfter:(NSTimeInterval)delay{

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:view animated:YES];
    // Configure for text only and offset down
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
    hud.labelText = title;

    hud.detailsLabelText = message;
    hud.margin = 10.f;
    hud.yOffset = 0.0f;
    hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
    [hud hide:YES afterDelay:delay];

});

}
```

Then in your code when you start the background task, call showMessage and then the upload is done, remove it.

Comment: Didn't use it with that method but MBProgressHUD is awesome! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You are dismissing the ViewController twice in your method if it is successful. Obviously, this can't be done. I don't know what exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I think removing the first `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]` would do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the one method doesn't really explain whats going on. Basically the user is presented with a view that has a button to choose a picture or to choose one later. If they press the button to choose a picture, the UIImagePickerController is modally presented. When the user selects a file, the UIImagePickerController is dismissed and the loading view is presented. After the file uploads, the loading view is dismissed and they are presented with a modified version of the screen they started on.

Comment: So removing that line warns that the load view was attempted to be presented on the main view controller whose main view was not in the window hierarchy.

"Warning: Attempt to present <LoadingViewController: 0x11f46990> on <UITabBarController: 0xb997a40> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: well, that's an error not related to this question, but it solves the bug you describe, since the error disappeared. Regardless of the implementation, you can't perform an action that can only be performed once, twice.